# Irregular spacing pcolor plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

The following python code works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as P
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

# A is a matrix of dimension [101,1000]
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:100:100.0/101, -5:20:25.0/1000]
P.pcolor(X, Y, A, norm=LogNorm(vmin=np.min(A), vmax=np.max(A)), cmap='PuBu_r')
P.colorbar()
```

However what I would like is to plot the same colorplot data but with a different X axis. I would like the first 50 points in X to be between 0 and 50 and the last 51 points to be between 50 and 150 (non regular grid). The actual A matrix is on that grid 0-150 and not on the 0-100 grid that I currently plot.

I tried to interpolate the data with griddata but was unsuccessful. Any suggestions for an elegant way to do this ?

Comment: Check e.g. `X, Y = np.meshgrid([1,5,12,30,50], [1,2,3,4,5])` and adapt it too your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works but you need to do X.T and Y.T because meshgrid return the transpose of what you get with mgrid.

Comment: Not really, it's rather that `X,Y = meshgrid(x,y)`, so you need to mind the order of arguments.

Comment: Check this website http://louistiao.me/posts/numpy-mgrid-vs-meshgrid/ seems it returns the transpose of the other.